# Creating a collection of functions

Tags: collections, clojure, higher-order-functions

I have the following function that receives a list of functions:

```
(defn foo
  [fn-list]
  (map #(%) fn-list))
```

I want to pass it instances of this `bar` function as a parameter.

```
(defn bar
  [x]
  (println x))
```

My problem is that I only have a list of arguments for `bar`. Fox example, a simple list `("a" "b" "c")`. I want to create a list of `bar` functions, each having as argument, an element of the later collection.

Can someone show me how this can be done? Thanks.

Note: I can't simply replace `foo` with `(map bar ("a" "b" "c"))` for reasonable reasons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear what you are trying to do, but perhaps you want something like:

```
(map #(partial bar %) [1 2 3])
```

This will create a sequence of functions, which when called (with 0 arguments) will do the equivalent of `(bar 1)`, `(bar 2)` etc.

Comment: An alternative: `(for [x [1 2 3]] #(bar x))`